# Hearing "element 'behavior' has invalid child element" should be ignored, but prevented from updating service reference because of it

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The element ‘behavior’ has invalid child element ‘myFaultExtension’ in wcf app.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677377/the-element-behavior-has-invalid-child-element-myfaultextension-in-wcf-app-c)

I'm trying to implement [Creating and Handling Faults in Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470096%28VS.95%29.aspx).  ([This](http://www.benday.com/2010/08/16/how-to-permanently-banish-silverlights-not-found-error-for-wcf-service-calls/) project works on my machine.)

I get a Visual Studio warning:

> The element 'behavior' has invalid child element 'betterErrorMessagesFaults'.

Other answers elsewhere say I should just ignore it, but I can't because I'm not able to update the service reference in the non .Web project (the one with all the xaml files). When I try, I get this error:

> Parser Error Message: The type 'MyProject.Web.Services.BetterErrorMessagesFaultBehavior, MyProject.Web.Services, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' registered for extension 'betterErrorMessagesFaults' could not be loaded.

Here's the relevant part of Web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <extensions>
    <behaviorExtensions>
      <add name="betterErrorMessagesFaults" 
        type="MyProject.Web.Services.BetterErrorMessagesFaultBehavior, MyProject.Web.Services, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
    </behaviorExtensions>
  </extensions>
  <services>
    <service name="MyProject.Web.Services.Service2">
      <endpoint address="" binding="customBinding" 
          bindingConfiguration="MyProject.Web.Services.Service2.customBinding0" 
          contract="MyProject.Web.Services.Service2" 
          behaviorConfiguration="BetterErrorMessagesFaultBehavior"/>
      <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="BetterErrorMessagesFaultBehavior">
        <betterErrorMessagesFaults/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <bindings>
    <customBinding>
      <binding name="MyProject.Web.Services.Service2.customBinding0">
        <binaryMessageEncoding>
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
            maxDepth="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" 
            maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />
        </binaryMessageEncoding>
        <httpTransport maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
            maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
      </binding>
    </customBinding>
  </bindings>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

The `BetterErrorMessagesFaultBehavior` is just a copy-paste of the class [here on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470096%28VS.95%29.aspx); with only the name changed (I tried with default name as well), and the namespace changed to `MyProject.Web.Services`.

I also tried exchanging

```
<add name="betterErrorMessagesFaults" 
    type="MyProject.Web.Services.BetterErrorMessagesFaultBehavior, MyProject.Web.Services, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
```

with

```
<add name="betterErrorMessagesFaults" 
    type="MyProject.Web.Services.BetterErrorMessagesFaultBehavior, MyProject.Web.Services"/>
```

but there was no effect. I read this is extremely sensitive to spaces etc., but I can't see any problem areas. I also looked at the AssemblyInfo and the version is 1.0.0.0, culture is just blank (""), and I don't know what PublicKeyToken is for, but I suspect that is not the problem here...

So I am stumped, no idea where to look next.

Answer (score 4):

Probably more than a little bit late, but you could verify you have the type designation right by executing something like:

`Console.WriteLine(typeof(BetterErrorMessagesFaultBehavior).AssemblyQualifiedName);`

That should contain the PublicKeyToken portion for you to compare...