# WCF implement IErrorHandler run into registered for extension 'enforceGreetingFaults' could not be loaded

Tags: wcf, web-config

I have an old WCF project that receives xml type of post-call.
Recently, the caller says they are facing 500 while calling our endpoint.
But when we checked the log, there was no record related to the failed call.

After investigating further, we think the call was never executed/enter the method correctly so there was no log.
The call didn't hit the method since xml content in the post was truncated so it failed to deserialize the parameter.
For example

```
<!-- missing </PartNumberUpdate> -->
<PartNumberUpdate>
  <PartNumbers>
    <PartNumber>
      <LicenseNo>001</LicenseNo>
      <Description>xxx</Description>
    </PartNumber>
    <PartNumber>
      <LicenseNo>001</LicenseNo>
      <Description>yyy</Description>
    </PartNumber>
  <PartNumbers> 

// the xml in post can't convert to param input cause it's incomplete
public void ProcessPartNumberUpdate(PartNumberUpdate input)
{
    ...
}
```

But the caller claimed the XML they posted was complete and since the call never hit the method we don't have any log to tell if that is true.

Therefore, I'm trying to figure out a way to log the error even when the method is not executed.
I searched a bit online and it seems [IErrorHandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.ierrorhandler?view=netframework-4.8.1&redirectedfrom=MSDN) meets my requirement the best.

However, after transplanting the code and the xml setting to my project from the instructions.
I ran into

> The type 'Microsoft.WCF.Documentation.EnforceGreetingFaultBehavior,
> HostApplication, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null' registered for extension 'enforceGreetingFaults'
> could not be loaded.

While IIS expresses the web service from Visual Studio.

There is also a warning in Error List

> The element 'behavior' has invalid child element
> 'enforceGreetingFaults'. List of possible elements expected:
> 'serviceAuthenticationManager, clear, serviceAuthorization,
> serviceCredentials, serviceMetadata, serviceSecurityAudit,
> serviceThrottling, dataContractSerializer, serviceDebug,
> serviceTimeouts, remove, useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress,
> persistenceProvider, workflowRuntime, etwTracking, bufferedReceive,
> workflowIdle, workflowUnhandledException, sendMessageChannelCache,
> sqlWorkflowInstanceStore, workflowInstanceManagement,
> serviceDiscovery, routing'.

I wonder if it's since my WCF is quite very old? but I have updated the target framework to 4.7.2.

I created a class ServiceHostGeneralErrorHandler with all C# code from the instruction.
And transplant the xml setting to mine as

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="loggingConfiguration" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.LoggingSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" requirePermission="true"/>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="MyPorjectMetadata_RESTService.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <loggingConfiguration name="" tracingEnabled="true" defaultCategory="General" logWarningsWhenNoCategoriesMatch="false">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Event Log Listener" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.FormattedEventLogTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.FormattedEventLogTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" source="MyPorjectMetadata" formatter="Text Formatter" log="MyPorjectMetadata" machineName="." traceOutputOptions="None"/>
    </listeners>
    <formatters>
      <add type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Formatters.TextFormatter, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" template="Message: {message}{newline}" name="Text Formatter"/>
    </formatters>
    <categorySources>
      <add switchValue="All" name="General">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Event Log Listener"/>
        </listeners>
      </add>
    </categorySources>
    <specialSources>
      <allEvents switchValue="Off" name="All Events"/>
      <notProcessed switchValue="Off" name="Unprocessed Category"/>
      <errors switchValue="Off" name="Logging Errors &amp; Warnings">
        <listeners>
          <add name="Event Log Listener"/>
        </listeners>
      </errors>
    </specialSources>
  </loggingConfiguration>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp>
        <network host="smtp-americas.my-company.com" port="25"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyPorjectMetadata_RESTService.Properties.Settings.strConnectionString" connectionString="server=.;database=my-companyDistributionKeyStore;Trusted_Connection=Yes; application name=MyPorjectMetadata_RESTService"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="largeMessageBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="4194304"/>
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="MyPorjectMetadata_RESTService.Service1Behavior" name="MyPorjectMetadata_RESTService.Service1">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="MyPorjectMetadata_RESTService.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="web" bindingConfiguration="largeMessageBinding">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyPorjectMetadata_RESTService.Service1Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <enforceGreetingFaults/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add
          name="enforceGreetingFaults"
          type="Microsoft.WCF.Documentation.EnforceGreetingFaultBehavior, HostApplication, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
        />
      </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <applicationSettings>
    <MyPorjectMetadata_RESTService.Properties.Settings>
    <!-- some properites -->
    </MyPorjectMetadata_RESTService.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

I think perhaps it's because I don't have the dll? So I tried to find `Microsoft.WCF.Documentation.EnforceGreetingFaultBehavior` from Nuget but can't find anything like it.

To sum up my question,

1. How to resolve this extension can't be loaded issue?
2. Or is there an alternative way to capture the post error instead?

Comment: This post can help you.[The element 'behavior' has invalid child element 'myFaultExtension' in wcf app.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677377/the-element-behavior-has-invalid-child-element-myfaultextension-in-wcf-app-c)

Answer (score 0):

My senior colleague guide me the usage.

The key is, `Microsoft.WCF.Documentation.EnforceGreetingFaultBehavior` is something we should write our own.
So you need to create the class (for `IServiceBehavior`) under your project.

```
public class EnforceGreetingFaultBehavior : BehaviorExtensionElement, IServiceBehavior
{
    public override Type BehaviorType => typeof(EnforceGreetingFaultBehavior);

    public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase, Collection<ServiceEndpoint> endpoints, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
        return;
    }

    public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        IErrorHandler errorHandler = new ServiceHostGeneralErrorHandler();
        foreach (ChannelDispatcher cd in serviceHostBase.ChannelDispatchers)
        {
            cd.ErrorHandlers.Add(errorHandler);
        }
    }

    public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
    {
        return;
    }

    protected override object CreateBehavior()
    {
        return new EnforceGreetingFaultBehavior();
    }
}
```

Then a class for `IErrorHandler`

```
public class ServiceHostGeneralErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
{
    #region IErrorHandler Members
    public bool HandleError(Exception error)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("HandleError called.");
        // Returning true indicates you performed your behavior.
        return true;
    }

    // This is a trivial implementation that converts Exception to FaultException<GreetingFault>.
    public void ProvideFault(
      Exception error,
      MessageVersion ver,
      ref Message msg
    )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ProvideFault called. Converting Exception to GreetingFault....");
        FaultException<string> fe
          = new FaultException<string>(error.Message);
        MessageFault fault = fe.CreateMessageFault();
        msg = Message.CreateMessage(
          ver,
          fault,
          "http://microsoft.wcf.documentation/ISampleService/SampleMethodGreetingFaultFault"
        );
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Lastly, in web.config `behaviorExtensions`, you need the correct assembly qualified name

```
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add
      name="enforceGreetingFaults"
      type="MyPorjectMetadata_RESTService.ServiceBehaviors.EnforceGreetingFaultBehavior, MyPorjectMetadata_RESTService, Version=2.0.0.5, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"
    />
  </behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
```

You may get qualified name by

```
string qn = typeof(EnforceGreetingFaultBehavior).Assembly.FullName.ToString();
```

After implemention above, `<enforceGreetingFaults/>` in `serviceBehaviors` should work correctly and you can put a break point in `ServiceHostGeneralErrorHandler.HandleError(Exception error)` to check exception catch.